# MTP Not Working Showing: /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-mtp (No such file or directory)

Tags: 16.04, usb, android, mtp

Opened the laptop and just connected the device it was detected and showed the device but when I tried to open it following message came up

```
"/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-mtp" (No such file or directory)
```

And due to some work I have to shutdown but when I restarted the laptop the device was not showing up on the nautilus.

The device is samsung j2 running on android 6.0.1
I have tried wth different cables and even tried with another phone but same result nothing shows up.

note:I am a complete noob at ubuntu just installed it a week ago so plz be 
a little discriptive.

Edit:

command:

`ls -l /usr/lib/gvfs/`

output:

`total 472
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  31912 May 18  2016 gvfsd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  31872 May 18  2016 gvfsd-burn
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  40528 May 18  2016 gvfsd-computer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  36384 May 18  2016 gvfsd-fuse
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  44216 May 18  2016 gvfsd-localtest
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  77680 May 18  2016 gvfsd-metadata
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  48752 May 18  2016 gvfsd-trash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 166200 May 18  2016 gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor`

Edit 2:
command:`sudo apt-get install gvfs-backends`

output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gvfs-backends : Depends: libsmbclient (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1) but it is not 
going to be installed
             Depends: gvfs (= 1.28.1-1ubuntu1) but 1.28.2-
1ubuntu1~16.04.1 is to be installed
             Depends: gvfs-daemons (= 1.28.1-1ubuntu1)
             Depends: gvfs-libs (= 1.28.1-1ubuntu1) but 1.28.2-
1ubuntu1~16.04.1 is to be installed
             Depends: gvfs-common (= 1.28.1-1ubuntu1) but 1.28.2-
1ubuntu1~16.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can I ask you why you are shouting in the title?

Comment: Didn't notice..... :p

Comment: Can you open a terminal window, and enter the command `ls -l /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-mtp` and edit your question to include the output of the command?

Comment: `ls -l /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-mtp` was giving `ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-mtp': No such file or directory` so i went up a little and added the output .

Comment: It seems that you need to install `gvfs-backends` package with `sudo apt-get install gvfs-backends` for needed file.

Comment: Tried @N0rbert 's command `sudo apt-get install gvfs-backends` but another problem came up I've given the output of command in the post

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install -f; sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Answer (score 3):

For users who were out of luck with mtpfs, jmtpfs, go-mtpfs or any other libraries which depend on libmtp; try **android-file-transfer**.

It does not depend on libmtp and thus free from inherent bugs, is the most up-to-date mtp library I have seen on github (as of May 2018), and also can be used with FUSE, although I personally recommend to use its own Qt based GUI to avoid possible FUSE back-front interaction bugs.

Just make sure you DO NOT open your MTP device using any default mechanisms provided by your linux distro, e.g. clicking on Open when the device-connected notification pops up!

github: https://github.com/whoozle/android-file-transfer-linux

PPA: https://launchpad.net/~samoilov-lex/+archive/ubuntu/aftl-stable

Read about MTP on linux: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MTP

P.S.: I'm only a user of the this application.

Comment: I got same issue the solution for me is removing `jmtpfs` and  `gvfs`

Answer (score 0):

you need to install  gvfs package from https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gvfs

Please disconnect the phone while installing the package.

Comment: Never wise to just rely on a link for an answer... if the link is removed or becomes broken it renders your answer useless.